# Prove that an ideal $I = (f)$ is prime if and only if $f$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra

In my lecture notes, we have the statement and proof of the following:

Let $I = (f) \subseteq \mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ be an ideal. $I$ is a prime ideal if and only if $f$ is an irreducible polynomial.

The proof we're given is sort of long, and I had an idea that I think shortens it a bit, although my idea seems obvious, so I wanted to check it here.

**Proof**

For the forward implication,

$I =(f)$  a prime ideal $\implies I \neq \mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$, so $f$ is non-constant.

Assume for contradiction that $f$ is reducible. Then we can write $f = f_1f_2$ for $f_1,f_2 \in \mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ both non-constant, so that $\deg f_1 \lt \deg f$ and $\deg f_2 \lt \deg f$.

Now, $I$ is prime, so either $f_1 \in I$ or $f_2 \in I$. Assume $f_1 \in I$. Then $ f_1 = fg$ for $g \in \mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$. This is a contradiction, because $\deg f_1 \lt \deg f$. Similarly for $f_2$. Thus we have that $I$ prime $\implies$ $f$ irreducible.

For the converse, let $f$ be irreducible, and let $f_1f_2 \in I$. Then $f_1f_2 = fg$ for $g \in \mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$. By irreducibility of $f$, either $f |f_1$ or $f|f_2$ in $\mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$, and so either $f_1 \in I$ or $f_2 \in I$, completing the proof.

Does the above work?

Comment: Have you proved that $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a UFD? If not, your attempted proof of the converse is circular.

Comment: The first direction is the easy one, and it's good to start there.  However the second part is a bit muddled.  Think about the definition of $I$ as a prime ideal in contrast to $f$ as a prime element.  We are told that $f$ is an irreducible element, not that it is a prime element.  The challenge is in making that leap.

Comment: @quasi Yes, we may assume that to be true, we've proven it before.

Comment: @hardmath sorry, I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. Could you direct me more precisely to what I've got wrong/muddled?

Comment: @Matt S: Yes, if you have unique factorization, then your proof is OK. Perhaps a few more steps are needed (e.g., show the factorization of $f_1$ and $f_2$ into irreducibles, and argue that one of the irreducible factors of $f_1$ or $f_2$ must be a unit times $f$).

Comment: More precisely prime elements are always irreducible, but the converse is not always true.  Here you will need that the polynomials over a field are a UFD, as @quasi is pointing out.

Comment: I understand. So what you're saying is that my proof is technically correct but that's on the basis that I'm in a UFD, and perhaps adding that justification in would be helpful (along with a couple of other steps as @quasi recommends)?

Comment: Theorem: In a UFD, a nonzero element is a prime if and only if it is irreducible. we can see a proof in the book "abstract algebra, David Dummit, Richard Foote, p286 "